# Hibernate Query DetachedCriteria VS bulkUpdate SQL using Collection with "in" Calause Problem

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I facing a problem on how to use SQL "in" in bulkUpdate Hibernate.

Example :

Country is an enum type.
**Normal SQL statement**

```
Update Persons SET country = Country.China
WHERE country IN (Country.HK, Country.Taiwan);
```

**Hibernate using DetachedCriteria**

```
DetachedCriteria criteria= DetachedCriteria.forClass(Persons.class)
 .add(Property.forName("country").in(countryList));
List<Persons> personsList = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);

for(Persons persons : personsList){
     person.setCountry(Country.China);
}

personsDao.updateAll(personsList);
personsDao.flush();
```

**Hibernate using bulkUpdate problem - Does not work!**

```
getHibernateTemplate().bulkUpdate(
"select * from Persons where country in (?)",
 new Object[] {countryList});
```

**Error message:**

```
[Lcom.model.Persons.Country; cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum]
```

But I tried this one. It works.
[ Not using Object : I hardcode it]

```
getHibernateTemplate().bulkUpdate(
"select * from Persons where country in (" + Country.HK + "," + Country.Taiwan +" )" );
```

Here the Question:
1. Can we use Object [] with "in" Clause?
2. I wonder why the system know the Object is a Country Enum.

Example :

```
getHibernateTemplate().bulkUpdate(
"select * from Persons where country = ?",
 new Object[] {country});
```

==> It working and executable.

1. Beside Collection of Enum ( example above ), List or String [] also not working using Object with "in" Clause.

Hope you guys can solve my problem.
Thanks.
-fsloke

Answer (score 0):

ok, I just have a simple question.  Are you sure that your countryList is a List of Country and not just a single County object?  If you use in (?) It expects a collection.